# Geometry instancing in Silverlight 5.0 - is it possible?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, geometry-instancing

I am working on Silverlight 5.0 app. Because I am rendering a lot of models at once (hundreds of them) I would like to use geometry instancing. Unfortunatelly from my research i found out that silverlight uses shader model 2.0. Is it possible to perform instancing then? In xna 4.0 there is method

`GraphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives()`

Although I can' t see it in Silverlight. **Is it possibly to use hardware instancing in Silverlight?**

If not  - are there some alternatives to increase performance of my app? The problem is that, I am calling `graphicsDevice.SetPixelShader()` and `graphicsDevice.SetVertexShader()` few thousands time in my `Draw()` method.

Comment: What kind of geometries do you want to render ? How do you get them ? How do you render them ? Path Geometries are really efficient, this might be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @xum59 I am rendering a large ammount (few hundreds) of cuboids - each covered with three unique textures (one of them is common for each cuboid in the scene). Also each of them has different word matrix, and different dimmensions.